# CSS imports are not concatenated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I have a rails 3 app and I am using the assets pipeline. In my `application.css.scss` I have if I do this:

```
@import 'foo.css';
```

after I compile the assets, `foo.css` is not concatenated in `application.css` instead the `@import` statemen becomes:

```
@import url(foo.css);
```

Is there some way I can force concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@import "foo.scss";
```

or

```
@import "foo";
```

it will work fine for more information go through this http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: so does my `foo.css` have to have a `.scss` extension to get concatenation to work?

Comment: css files you can add it like his `/* ... *= require foo*/` check it from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives

Comment: This comment was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!